# MenuItem Highlight Stays After MouseLeave

Tags: wpf, vb.net, menuitem

I have this menuitem inside of a combobox:

```
<MenuItem Name="CurrencySelectMenuItem" Header="Currency" Width="Auto" 
          Background="Black" Foreground="White" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0" 
          BorderBrush="Black" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
```

When I highlight the item, it does what I want: it pops up the way it should to display it's children, and highlights to show that it's focused. However, when the mouse leaves, the menuitem stays highlighted, even after clicking some other part of my application.

I tried setting the IsFocused property but it is read only.

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

EDIT (code added):

```
 <Grid>
<ComboBox Name="SettingsCmbx" Text="Options" Foreground="White" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Width="80" Style="{StaticResource blackGradientComboBox}" Margin="3">
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <!--<ComboBoxItem Name="Options" IsEnabled="False" Style="{StaticResource blackComboBoxItem}">Options</ComboBoxItem>-->
            <ComboBoxItem Style="{StaticResource blackComboBoxItem}">Guidelines</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Style="{StaticResource blackComboBoxItem}">Copy Investigation</ComboBoxItem>
            <MenuItem Name="CurrencySelectMenuItem" Header="Currency" Background="Black" Foreground="White" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0" BorderBrush="Black" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <MenuItem Name="DollarSelectMenuItem" Header="_$ - Dollar" Background="Black" Foreground="White"></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Name="PoundSelectMenuItem" Header="_£ - Pound" Background="Black" Foreground="White"></MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Style="{StaticResource blackComboBoxItem}">About</ComboBoxItem>
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>
<TextBlock Name="OptionsTxtBlk" Text="Options" IsHitTestVisible="False" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
 </Grid>
```

Here's the image:
[image]

Comment: Post more code, like XAML for your Combobox.

Comment: Someone must've had this problem? sthotakura - do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Is there any reason, you are using `ComboBox` instead of the usual `Menu`?

Comment: I tried your sample code, For me, the menu doesn't even open.